# How to convert ArrayList<String> to a\array<out String> in kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin, android-workmanager

my Data.builder() method putStringArray() takes parameter as key : String and value : Array

how do I convert my ArrayList into Array?

```
fun createInputData(dataItems : ArrayList<String>) : Data
    {
       
        return Data.Builder()
                .putStringArray("dataItems",dataItems)
                .build()
    }
```

the above code doesn't work.

Comment: and how do i convert it back to an arraylist of string?

Comment: you can use `.toList()` extention method for `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataItems.toTypedArray()` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below method:-

**Convert To Array:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    // an arraylist of vowels
    val vowels_list: List<String> = listOf("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    
    // converting arraylist to array
    val vowels_array: Array<String> = vowels_list.toTypedArray()
    
    // printing elements of the array 
    vowels_array.forEach { System.out.print(it) }
}
```

**Convert To List:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    // vowels array
    val vowels_array: Array<String> = arrayOf("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    
    // converting array to array list
    val vowels_list: List<String> = vowels_array.toList()
    
    // printing elements of the array list
    vowels_list.forEach { System.out.print(it) }
}
```

Comment: and how do i convert it back to an arraylist of string?